# rails 5 api app with json error response instead of html error response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, http

If I create an app in rails using the --api flag my error responses are in html rather than json.

How am I able to change the default error handler so that whenever an error is thrown in a controller action, I receive a json only response with the error and http status?

right now I am using the code below in every custom action

```
rescue => e
    response.status = 422
    render json: { error: e.message }
```

I'd rather not have to add this each time...

UPDATE: 
I used the rescue_from method in the application controller

```
rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    render json: exception, status: 500
end
```

But I feel this is very wrong and the status will always be hard coded as 500

Comment: You can add rescue_from in your application_controller to catch every single error
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from

Comment: If I do that I won't have the status that I would normally receive... how is this not built in already??

Comment: Hmm, I do not totally get what you really want. But if you want to render with different message and status depends on Exception, then you can set multiple rescue_from. 

Or you could define multiple error_render methods and sort it in the one big rescue_from.


PS: also please do not rescue Exception. change it to StandardError.

Comment: I added  defaults: { format: :json }  to my route and it converted it - I'm still after a default format change for all routes however so any suggestions to the configuration would be appreciated :)

Comment: NEVER `rescue_from Exception` Exception is a superclass of some kinds of Exceptions that you never want to rescue from like system signals. (as Bagi said, I'm just making sure it's visible)

Comment: good point, thanks for commenting this @radixhound

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add format as json in routes so it will always accept request in json format like below

```
namespace :api, as: nil, defaults: { format: :json } do
     devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: "api/v1/users/registrations",
        passwords: "api/v1/users/passwords"
      }

      resources :products, only: [:show,:index] do
        get "check_product_avaibility"
        get "filter", on: :collection
      end
end
```

For handling errors globally, you can add around_action in application controller file

```
around_action :handle_exceptions, if: proc { request.path.include?('/api') }

# Catch exception and return JSON-formatted error
  def handle_exceptions
    begin
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      @status = 404
      @message = 'Record not found'
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      render_unprocessable_entity_response(e.record) && return
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      @status = 400
    rescue StandardError => e
      @status = 500
    end
    json_response({ success: false, message: @message || e.class.to_s, errors: [{ detail: e.message }] }, @status) unless e.class == NilClass
  end
```

**NOTE: render_unprocessable_entity_response and json_response are custom methods , you can add your own methods to render json response.**

Comment: But since the --api flag was introduced, surely they would have changed the the default response to json? Isn't there an easy config that can be changed? I'm surprised it's not built in...your code above is adding code to what I thought would have been added to the rails framework...

Comment: yes, i am sture because i done it in many applications. its not built in , you have to mention there for response to json and for json request you need to specify format  in route

Comment: Thanks Vishal, specifying the format in the routes (which means I will have to add it to all routes) sorted the problem out. I added ``` defaults: { format: :json } ``` to my route

Comment: Yes. you can also do that.

Comment: Wanted to add many people coming to this answer will be looking for debug_exception_response_format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [api_error_handler gem](https://github.com/jamesstonehill/api_error_handler).

Include it in your bundler file:

```rb
gem "api_error_handler", "~> 0.2.0"
```

The in your application controller, invoke the library.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  handle_api_errors(
    # Error handling options go here if you want to override any defaults.
  )

  # ...
end
```

Now if you have a controller like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise 'SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!'
  end
end
```

When you hit this endpoint you will see this response

```json
{
  "error": {
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "detail": "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!"
  }
}
```

And the status code will be set to an appropriate status code based on the type of error you had.

See the gem's [README](https://github.com/jamesstonehill/api_error_handler) for more info on how to configure the error response.

Comment: It's not working for me because of this issue https://github.com/jamesstonehill/api_error_handler/issues/21